# How to specify Chrome browser in an HTML hyperlink

Tags: html, google-chrome, browser, protocols, href

[This](https://www.itworld.com/article/3008858/development/how-to-open-specific-web-browsers-using-hyperlinks.html) gives an Edge example with `<a href='microsoft-edge:http://mylinkhere.com'></a>` but is there a prefix I can add to a hyperlink to make it open in Chrome?

I have a program sending HTML emails with `<a href='google-chrome:http://mylocalhostprogram>Click here</a>` but I get "There is no program associated to perform the requested action." I tried prefixing just `chrome` too but that did not work.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Do you need it to open in chrome? I mean what if I don't have chrome and Edge? I would just remove it altogether

Comment: @Huangism yes I need it to open in Chrome, it's a business application where the users will specifically be using Chrome and there is certain functionality that only works in Chrome

Comment: Maybe this can help https://forums.asp.net/t/1754195.aspx?I+want+to+create+a+web+url+shortcut+on+desktop+to+open+only+in+google+chrome

Comment: The only relevant thing I found is `googlechromes://apple.stackexchange.com/` but I think it only works on iOS